# Serverless YML toUpperCase

Tags: yaml, serverless

I want to reuse my `serverless.yml` in different environments (dev, test, prod).

In the config I have:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
```

Right now the value will be `dev`, `test` or `prod` (all in lower-case).

Is there a way to convert it toUpperCase() in a way that the input and `self:provider:stage` will **stay** as it is (i.e. lower-case) but the value of NODE_ENV will be UPPER-CASE?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Update (2022-10-13)*

This answer was correct at the time of its writing (circa 2018). A better answer now is to use [`serverless-plugin-utils`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-utils) as stated in @ShashankRaj's comment below.

```
varName: ${upper(value)}
```

---

AFAIK, there is no such function in YAML.

You can achieve what you want though by using a map between the lowercase and uppercase names.

```
custom:
  environments:
    dev: DEV
    test: TEST
    prod: PROD

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.environments.${self:provider.stage}}
```

Comment: I was thinking about it as potential workaround and I used similar technique. I was wondering is there a better or proper way. Anyway, if there is nothing then I can use a map. Thanks!

Comment: For someone who might still be looking for a solution, https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-utils is a serverless utils plugin that can help with a bunch of these utility functions.
The fn: upper function can be used for the above case.

Comment: @ShashankRaj's solution is correct and should be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve something to this effect using the [reference variables in javascript files](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files) functionality provided.

To take your example, this should work (assuming you're running in a node.js environment that supports modern syntax)

**serverless.yml**

```
...
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${file(./yml-helpers.js):provider.stage.uppercase}
...
```

**yml-helpers.js** (adjacent to serverless.yml)

```js
module.exports.provider = serverless => {
  // The `serverless` argument containers all the information in the .yml file
  const provider = serverless.service.provider;

  return Object.entries(provider).reduce(
    (accumulator, [key, value]) => ({
      ...accumulator,
      [key]:
        typeof value === 'string'
          ? {
              lowercase: value.toLowerCase(),
              uppercase: value.toUpperCase()
            }
          : value
    }),
    {}
  )
};
```

Comment: This always returns DEV despite specifying --stage=foo . I am using serverless@1.71.0

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at something that works, via reading some source code and console logging the entire `serverless` object.  This example applies a helper function to title-case some input option values (apply `str.toUpperCase()` instead, as required).  There is a result of parsing the input options already available in the serverless object.

```js
// serverless-helpers.js

function toTitleCase(word) {
  console.log("input word:  " + word);
  let lower = word.toLowerCase();
  let title = lower.replace(lower[0], lower[0].toUpperCase());
  console.log("output word: " + title);
  return title;
}

module.exports.dynamic = function(serverless) {
  // The `serverless` argument contains all the information in
  // the serverless.yaml file
  // serverless.cli.consoleLog('Use Serverless config and methods as well!');

  // this is useful for discovery of what is available:
  // serverless.cli.consoleLog(serverless);

  const input_options = serverless.processedInput.options;
  return {
    part1Title: toTitleCase(input_options.part1),
    part2Title: toTitleCase(input_options.part2)
  };
};
```

```yaml
# serverless.yaml snippet

custom:

  part1: ${opt:part1}
  part2: ${opt:part2}

  dynamicOpts: ${file(./serverless-helpers.js):dynamic}
  combined: prefix${self:custom.dynamicOpts.part1Title}${self:custom.dynamicOpts.part2Title}Suffix
```

This simple example assumes the input options are `--part1={value}` and `--part2={value}`, but the generalization is to traverse the properties of `serverless.processedInput.options` and apply any custom helpers to those values.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Serverless Plugin Utils](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-utils):

```yaml
plugins:
 - serverless-plugin-utils

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${upper(${self:provider.stage})}
```

Thanks to @ShashankRaj...

Comment: `${upper(self:provider.stage)}` would output `SELF:PROVIDER.STAGE`.

Use `${upper(${self:provider.stage})}` to get the expected result.